# Global array not being accessed correctly

Tags: c#

Below is my current code:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int[] trialArray = new int[10];
        public int trialCounter = -1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool button1Click = true;
            if (button1Click == true) 
            {
                ITIpanel.Visible = true;   

                for (int i = 0; i < trialArray.Length; i++) { trialArray[i] = -1; } // Set default value through array

                int counter = 0;

                Random rnd = new Random();

                while (counter < 10 / 2)
                {  // Red trials, fill half array

                    int index = rnd.Next(0, 10 - 1);

                    if (trialArray[index] == -1) { trialArray[index] = 1; ++counter; } //if unchanged value, change it

                }
                while (counter < 10)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(0, 10);

                    if (trialArray[index] == -1) { trialArray[index] = 2; ++counter; }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ITIpanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ITIpanel.Visible == true)
            {
                trialCounter += 1; 
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ITIpanel.Visible = false;
            timer1.Enabled = false; 
            if (trialArray[trialCounter] == 1) { redstimPanel.Visible = true;  }

            else { bluestimPanel.Visible = true;}

            if (trialCounter == 9) { Application.Exit(); } 


        }
        public int counter = 0;
        public event EventHandler Clicked5TimesEvent;
        private void OnClicked5TimesEvent()
        { if (Clicked5TimesEvent != null) { Clicked5TimesEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); } }

        private void bluestimPanel_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //FR requirement
            counter++; if (counter % 5 == 0) { redstimPanel.Visible = false; ITIpanel.Visible = true; }
        }

        private void redstimPanel_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //FR requirement
            counter++; if (counter % 5 == 0) { redstimPanel.Visible = false; ITIpanel.Visible = true; }
        }


    }
}
```

As you can see, I am attempting to make a global array with 10 items. On the button click the 10 items are supposed to be altered such that half contain the value 1 and the other half contain the value 2.

Then, on the timer tick, depending on the value in the `trialCounter`, which determines the part of the array to be accessed, it should display either the `redstimPanel` or the `bluestimPanel`.

Therefore, if the 'trialCounter' is equal to 8, and 8 in the TrialArray is equal 1, the 'redstimPanel' should become Visible. Alternatively, if 8 in the 'TrialArray' is equal to 2, the 'bluestimPanel' should become Visible.

This, however, is not working as I would like it to. Thus, there are clearly some issues with my code. Do you all have any suggestions?

Comment: What is not working, exactly?

Comment: I don't know if my array has been modified correctly on the button click. I also don't know if my conditional statements on the timer tick are functioning properly either.

@Henk Holtman: The ITIpanel occurs frequently and every time it is made visible it marks the beginning of a Trial, thus I wanted it to add 1 to the counter to mark that another Trial has begun.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'll look into that. But I don't think how the 'trialCounter += 1;' adds to the int 'trialCounter' is what is causing my code to not work. I've used counters with the Paint event before and haven't had problems.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset counter, or have the second loop (the one setting the 2s) be the full array.

There is also an error with the random number, rnd.Next(a,b) a - lower bound (inclusive), b - upper bound (exclusive). So it should be rnd.Next(0,10); so you have a chance of populating the last array position.

```
while (counter < 10 / 2) { // Red trials, fill half array
    int index = rnd.Next(0, 10);

    if (trialArray[index] == -1) { trialArray[index] = 1; ++counter; } //if unchanged value, change it
}
//Counter on the first loop here is already 5 (it exited the previous loop)
//So allow it to get to 10, and populate the FULL array.
while (counter < 10) {
    int index = rnd.Next(0, 10);

    if (trialArray[index] == -1) { trialArray[index] = 2; ++counter; }
}
```

Comment: Alright. So if I change my code to 'while (count <10 / 2)' will that fix that problem?

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but this won't work.  The counter is only being incremented when it finds an unassigned value, so it will never get to 10.  This part of the code should work as Op wrote it.

Comment: Change the second loop to while(counter<10), that should fix it. Also noticed another problem..That your rnd.Next(..) should be rnd.Next(0,10), the 0 is INCLUSIVE, and 10 EXCLUSIVE according to the doc

Comment: @ptay89 Even after making those changes the code still functions as before. It will only display the bluestimPanel. What should happen is that Array of 10 things should be half 1 and half 2. Then when the conditional statement is triggered, it should access a specific part of the array dependent on the int value int the trialCounter. Thus, if the trialCounter = 5, and the 5th part of the Array is equal to 1, it should display a redstimPanel, and bluestimPanel if the 5th part of the array is equal to 2.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your only problem was with populating the array. Can you confirm the array is populated correctly now? One problem may be the ITIpanel_Paint(..), does that get called properly, I'd use the VisibilityChanged event myself.

Comment: @ptay89 I went back and tried your suggestion concerning the 'rnd.Next'. I changed it from 'rnd.Next (0, 10-1)' to 'rnd.Next(0, 10)' for both instances and I think that fixed it. I'll update this if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to give you some tips and some explanations regarding your code:

First of all, you probably wanted that local button1Click variable to know later on whether the button has been clicked or not. For that to work, you should place it outside that function, otherwise it's never going to be used, and will be true with every button click, something like this:

```
bool button1Click = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    if (!button1Click)
    {
```

1. When you have a condition, you want the code to decide, whether an expression is true or false you may  omit the part "== true" because it doesn't add anything new.
2. You have two whiles. Your idea was to run the counter until 5, with the first piece of code, and then from 5 to 10 the second piece of code. Now let me try to explain what is actually going on. The counter will go on until 5 filling 1s at random indices. Then at 5, the expression in the while will become false and it breaks out from the loop. Since the second while has the very same expression, it simply avoids it and goes on. One of the many solutions would be to have an if in the loop like this:

   while (counter < 10)
   {
        if (counter<5)
        {
            // fill red
        }
        else
        {
            // fill blue
        }
   }
3. The way you fill up the values in your array. Have you thought about what's going to happen when the same index will be generated several times? It means it'll overwrite the previous value while certain index will remain -1.

Comment: I assume "if (trialArray[index] == -1)" stops point 3 from happening? It makes sure it only overwrites it if its not already been written to, and the while loop gets another random number.